# Is my understanding correct of "In a fight for the states to sign on to the expansion"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

[Source](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/closeread/2013/11/notes-on-obamacare-the-coverage-gap-and-panic-trap.html) As I wrote in my comment, the Administration needs to engage fully and politically **in a fight for the states to, for example, sign on to** the Medicaid expansion.

> "in a fight for the states to sign on to the expansion"

This "for the states" is grammatically the same as "something for you to do."

Or "for the states to sign on to the expansion" is separate from the noun "fight" and explains "engage" like "I went to the park to talk to my neighbour"?

Comment: I didn't read the article, just scanned through it. But if I understand correctly, *a fight for the states* means a fight for those states in the United States. Roughly, that sentence means that the Administration should engage in a fight, and it is a fight to sign on to "the Medicaid expansion".

Answer (score 3):

This is a tricky sentence to parse, because that first *for* (the one after *fight*) actually serves two different purposes.

On the one hand it acts as a preposition in the idiomatic expression *fight for X*, meaning *struggle to achieve X*, where *fight* may be either a verb or a noun.

> Superman fights [<sub>preposition phrase</sub>**for** Truth, Justice and the American Way]!
>
> Superman’s fight [<sub>preposition phrase</sub>**for** Truth, Justice and the American Way]

In the sentence at hand, however, the object of that preposition is not a simple Noun Phrase but a subordinate clause of the form *for A to do B*, where *for* acts as a *complementizer*—in traditional grammar, a subordinating conjunction:

> What the administration wants is [<sub>complement clause</sub>**for** the states to sign on to the Medicaid expansion].
>   *which might be paraphrased as*
> What the administration wants is [<sub>complement clause</sub>**that** the states should sign on to the Medicaid expansion].

When that nominal complement clause headed by the complementizer *for* becomes the object of the preposition *for*, the two *for*s are collapsed into one.

> ... a fight ***for*** X
> *replace X with*       ***for*** the states to sign on to the Medicaid expansion
>              ↓
>        ... a fight ***for for*** the states to sign on to the Medicaid expansion
> *collapse the* for*s*
>              ↓
>        ... a fight ***for*** the states to sign on to the Medicaid expansion

This is not ungrammatical; it’s just one of those shortcuts nobody notices.

The sentence may be paraphrased:

> The Administration needs to engage ... in the effort to make the states sign on to the Medicaid expansion, among other things.

Comment: @kih1930 No. *For us to do* is adjectival, it acts as an adjective modifying *something*. *For the states to sign on* is nominal, it acts as the noun object of the pronoun *for* (or of the phrasal verb *fight for*, depending on how you understand phrasal verbs).

Comment: I see. But "for the states to sing on" explains "the fight" ? Is this what you are saying?

Comment: @kih1930 I've added some language that I hope explains this. Yes, the *for* phrase is a complement to *fight* which defines the ojbect which *fight* seeks to achieve.