# I am made to shut up or I was made to shut up

Tags: passive-voice, causative-make

I'm watching a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzEHgVbhdio&index=7&list=PL683FAB7A914D2944) about ***Passive Causative***;as of the minute [2:07](http://youtu.be/GzEHgVbhdio?t=2m7s)
there is a sentence written on the board that it's read as:

> I am made to shut up

Given that he is using the present form of the verb to be, should no be using *make* instead of *made*?

Also I found that the construction of *make* as a [causative](http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/let.html) is

> [make + person + verb]

and in this construction I don't see the **"person"**.

So my question is ***Is am correct or must be was and why?***

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/15376/3281. Also, you might want to check out this answer of mine: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/16399/3281, for typical mistakes students make related to active and passive verb forms in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given that he is using the present form of the verb to be, should no be using *make* instead of *made*?

No: *made* is correct. The passive voice is constructed from *be* plus the past participle. (In the case of *to make*, the form *made* serves as both past participle and past tense — and this is true of most English verbs — but you can see the difference with a verb like *to see*: we say "I am seen", not *"I am see" or *"I am saw".)

> […] and in this construction I don't see the **"person"**.

The "person" is the object of *make*. Your example uses the passive voice, so the object is converted to a subject (namely "I"). "I am made to shut up" means "[Someone] makes me shut up."

Answer (score 0):

The whole construction isn't brilliant. "Make somebody do something" is confortable in use "as is", when you start switching tenses, you may make a complete mess of it. 
As of some proposition instead, use "he was forced to shut up" or "they made him shut up", that will make your language rich and inventish.